# How to use NPM in conjunction with PHP/STATIC web site directory strucure?

Tags: javascript, php, css, npm, bootstrap-4

I have php web site with a structure like

```
/
   css/
   js/
   index.php
```

if I do, for example,

```
npm init
npm install bootstrap@4.6
```

it will create additionally

```
/
   node_modules/
      bootstrap/
         dist/
            css/
            js/
      ...
```

What next? Should I cahnge all paths within php-s to this strange long path `node_modules/boostrap/dist/js` or there is a way to copy required files to topmost directories `js/` and `css/`

Answer (score 2):

Normally you wouldn't use `node_modules` directly. Instead, you'd have a build step with a bundler like Webpack, Rollup, Vite, Parcel, etc. that knows how to bundle your site's assets with assets in `node_modules` into an optimized set of files for delivery. One reason for that is "tree shaking" — bundling up and include only the *parts* of the modules you have in `node_modules` that you actually use in the code. The other is that `node_modules` has a lot of files in it (READMEs, etc.) that there's just no reason to include on your site (provided you're giving all necessary attribution somewhere).

You *could* cherry-pick the files you need from `node_modules` (at least in some cases), but it's labor-intensive. You'd be better off finding deployment-ready versions of the modules you want. Another option is to use `unpkg.com` which provides a CDN for `npm` modules.

Comment: My page works offline, so CDN is not usable. Currently I am using cherry picking and deployment-ready versions, but was wishing to introduce some automation...

Comment: @Dims - That's what a bundler would provide. :-)